# Half-size WiFi adapter for Slim Tower case

Tags: pc, wifi, pcie

I bought Dell Vostro 3800 in a Slim Tower case. What WiFi adapter would fit into such a case?

- The case has the following dimensions 102 * 433 * 360mm (W * D * H), while popular WiFi adapters do not to fit. For instance, [TP Link TL-WN781ND](https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5519_TL-WN781ND.html) is too wide: 120.8 * 78.5 * 21.5mm.
- The case has PCI-e x16, PCI-e x1 and PCI slots free.

Comment: Just have to find one that comes with a half-size bracket.  If all your looking for is size, there are plenty out there.  Otherwise you need to give some more detail on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

## The [Rosewill RNX-AC1900PCE](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166121)

[image]

I'm guessing based off your post you want an internal adapter, and not a USB one. I'm a little surprised you want one at all given it already has an internal card, but hey–if you want a bit of an upgrade, here's your card.

As @SiXandSeven8ths said, you'll need a card with a low profile bracket. Luckily, almost every card comes with one–this one included!

Since you're working in a proprietary case and weird PSU, I decided against any cards with an external power connector. I also went with wireless AC, since you seem to be looking for an upgrade. [This left](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/wireless-network-card/#i=35&e=31&sort=price&page=1) the TP-Link Archer T6E AC1300, TRENDnet TEW-807ECH, Asus PCE-AC56, and our Rosewill card all around the same price point. Both the TP-Link and Asus cards seem to have massive compatibility issues with Windows 10 Fall Creator's Update, and the TRENDnet card seems to have some QC issues, leaving the Rosewill card.

Comment: It has internal card but only for Ethernet, not WiFi.